# Pearl Weapons vs Destroyer Weapons

Tags: guild-wars-2

Looking at GW2DB (and other crafting tools) recipes I found out at higher levels two categories of level 80 exotic weapons.

Let's pick an example: Cleric's Pearl Sabre and Cleric's Destroyer Sword

Looking at the stats they are the same: 904-1000 weapon power, +64 power, +90 healing, +64 toughness.

Looking at the recipe they are almost the same: Orichalcum Sword Hilt, Orichalcum Sword Blade, Cleric's Orichalcum Imbued Inscription... but the second one needs also 20 Destroyer Lodestones!

So now, considering that you get the same stats, with no additional benefits, except for eventual (probable) graphic differences, why should someone forge a Destroyer weapon?

EDIT to clarify and make an actual question:

Is there any difference except in visual appearance between Pearl weapons and Destroyer weapons?

Comment: Your awnser is in the question, because they look cooler :p

Comment: I was wondering if I'm missing something other than that... :P

Comment: This question needs to be clarified and formed into an actual question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hope my edit now made my question an actual question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences are purely visual.

ArenaNet have strived to make the high level gear different only in visual appearance to avoid the end-game gear grinding. Many items and weapons which are maximum stat exotics only vary by skin.

The only real exception to this is the Ascended Gear which caused some upset in the player-base. http://www.shacknews.com/article/76799/guild-wars-2-team-addresses-gear-grind-complaints